# Can I set the child of an object to be an object defined separetely in PugiXML?

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I want to configure a device using an XML file and was thinking that I can make the individual `pugi::xml_node`s first with the values I need and later on make them children of a document or some parent node. However, I seem to be doing something wrong.

Example that works:

```
#include "pugixml.hpp"

int main(){
    pugi::xml_document xml;
    pugi::xml_node configRecord = xml.append_child("configrecord");
    pugi::xml_node configGroup = configRecord.append_child("configgroup");
    configGroup.append_attribute("name") = "ftp server";
}
```

This works because I first create the parent document and then start branching by adding children. I was thinking that I can first make the node objects, store them into an array and parse that array to add them to the document. But this doesn't work.

```
#include "pugixml.hpp"

int main(){
    pugi::xml_node myNode;
    myNode.set_name("value");
    myNode.append_child(pugi::node_pcdata).set_value("enable");
    pugi::xml_document docu;
    docu.set_name("document");
    docu.child(myNode); // <- error here, cannot add child to document
}
```

Can I somehow use the strategy I was planning to or am I constrained to only adding children to an existing parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pugixml documentation](https://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#dom.cpp) states that `pugi::xml_node` is a non-owning pointer to actual node data stored in a `pugi::xml_document` object:

> `xml_node` is the handle to document node; it can point to any node in
> the document, including the document node itself. There is a common
> interface for nodes of all types; the actual node type can be queried
> via the `xml_node::type()` method. Note that `xml_node` is only a handle
> to the actual node, not the node itself

> Nodes and attributes do not exist without a document tree, so you
> can’t create them without adding them to some document.

It seems to me that your code doesn't throw errors when you try to manipulate `myNode` because default-constructed "null" nodes silently consume operations on them to make chaining easier:

> all operations are defined on empty nodes; generally the operations
> don’t do anything and return empty nodes/attributes or empty strings
> as their result [...] This is useful for chaining calls

Comment: You are right, I somehow missed that when skimming the documentation for this problem. It does look like the approach I was taking needs improvements.